# is this normal during the installation of rasa (anaconda) ti takes long time

Tags: tensorflow, rasa, rasa-x

during the installation of rasa with anaconda in the prompt (look at the img) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gySEU.jpg)it download many and meny version of tensorflow is that normal ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep that is totally normal to install those versions. Also yes the time does vary from system to system.